# 1064 - You have a syntax error in your SQL next to ''

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION calcular_preco (id_produto INT(11), customer_group_id_informado INT(11))
RETURNS DECIMAL(15, 4)

BEGIN

    DECLARE preco_normal DECIMAL(15, 4);
    DECLARE pd_preco DECIMAL(15, 4);
    DECLARE pd_percentual INT(1);
    DECLARE pd_somar INT(1);
    DECLARE preco_promocional DECIMAL(15, 4);
    DECLARE preco_final DECIMAL(15, 4);
    
    # Preço normal
    SELECT price
    INTO preco_normal
    FROM oc_product
    WHERE product_id = id_produto;

    # Preço diferenciado
    SELECT price, percentual, somar
    INTO pd_preco, pd_percentual, pd_somar
    FROM oc_product_discount
    WHERE product_id = id_produto
    AND ((date_start = '0000-00-00' OR date_start < NOW())
    AND (date_end = '0000-00-00' OR date_end > NOW()))
    AND customer_group_id = customer_group_id_informado
    AND quantity = '1'
    ORDER BY priority ASC
    LIMIT 1;

    # Se este produto tiver preço diferenciado, deverá ser feito o cálculo do preço final
    SELECT IF(pd_preco IS NOT NULL, IF(pd_percentual, IF(pd_somar, preco_normal + ((preco_normal * pd_preco)/100), preco_normal - ((preco_normal * pd_preco)/100)), pd_preco), NULL) AS preco_diferenciado
    INTO pd_preco;

    # Preço promocional
    SELECT price
    INTO preco_promocional
    FROM oc_product_special
    WHERE product_id = id_produto
    AND customer_group_id = customer_group_id_informado
    AND ((date_start = '0000-00-00' OR date_start < NOW())
    AND (date_end = '0000-00-00' OR date_end > NOW()))
    ORDER BY priority ASC
    LIMIT 1;

    SELECT CASE
        WHEN preco_promocional IS NULL AND pd_preco IS NULL THEN preco_normal
        WHEN preco_promocional IS NOT NULL AND pd_preco IS NULL THEN preco_promocional
        WHEN preco_promocional IS NULL AND pd_preco IS NOT NULL THEN pd_preco
        WHEN preco_promocional < pd_preco THEN preco_promocional
        ELSE pd_preco
    END
    INTO preco_final;
    
    RETURN preco_final;
END;
```

When executing this query in my database, it displays the error:

> ## 1064 - You have a syntax error in your SQL next to '' on line 6

Line 6:

```
DECLARE preco_normal DECIMAL(15, 4);
```

Apparently, after consulting the documentation, there is nothing wrong with this line. Did you know what the error was?

My version: 10.4.11-MariaDB.

Comment: Which line is line 6?

Comment: And edit your Question to include the `DELIMITERs`.  There some tricky things about their placement and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in this [link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delimiters/) the reason why the query doesn't work.

Assuming you are trying to query this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FortyTwo() RETURNS TINYINT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE x TINYINT;
 SET x = 42;
 RETURN x;
END;
```

This error happens:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version
> for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

The resolution for this is add delimiters this way:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION FortyTwo() RETURNS TINYINT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE x TINYINT;
  SET x = 42;
  RETURN x;
END 

//

DELIMITER ;
```

It's the same case. You need to add the delimiters.